# Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier '4'

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have the following error:

```
Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier '4' in file.php on line 410
```

Code on line 410:

```
preg_match_all("#$replacement_pattern#is", $text, $arr);
```

Can someone please help me to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you provide enough code to recreate the problem, ie include your $pattern with sample $text, and $array

Comment: Use `preg_match_all("#" . preg_quote($replacement_pattern, "#") . "#is", $text, $arr);`

Comment: All code here: http://wklej.org/id/3214643/

Comment: I think, that problem is here $replacement_pattern = preg_replace('#\{[A-Z0-9_]+\}#', '(.+?)', $replacement_pattern); but I can't fix it.

Comment: Try `$replacement_pattern = str_replace('#', '\\#', trim($row['bbcode_in'])`);`  (Line 396)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the pattern having an unescaped regex delimiter that is `#`  in your case.

At line 396, the `$row['bbcode_in']`  is a simple string, and all `#`  symbols can be escaped then, so that afterwards you could use `#`  as regex delimiters.

So, Line 396 must look like:

```
$replacement_pattern = str_replace('#', '\\#', trim($row['bbcode_in']));
```